# Ambiguous use of 'methodName' with UIColor extension

Tags: swift

I'm trying to define extension for `UIColor`

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(rgb:UInt){
        let red:CGFloat = CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0;
        let green:CGFloat = CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0;
        let blue:CGFloat = CGFloat(rgb & 0xFF)/255.0;

        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    class func applicationGreenColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.255, green: 0.804, blue: 0.470, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use any of added functions I'm getting following error:
Ambiguous use of 'applicationGreenColor'.

I have even tried to add very simple method like:

```
func info(){
    println(self.description);
}
```

Resulting in the same compile error: Ambiguous use of 'info'.

Hence initialisation from RGB unit works fine.

I have added multiple extensions for String and other classes but anything work with `UIColor`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Update** - I can see all methods defined in my UIImage extension methods appear twice in code completion suggestion.

Comment: I can build it without problems. Are you sure you are adding the method only once? Don't you have the same methods created in Obj-C, for example?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i don't have any duplication. It's empty project with one framework target and test target. I can build it fine as well, the problem is when I'm trying to compile test target to run tests:
 func testBlueColor() {
        let blueColor = UIColor.applicationBlueColor();
        XCTAssert(blueColor != nil, "Pass")
    }

Here it complains regarding ambiguous use of info method.

Comment: Strange, I can use it without problems.

Comment: Perhaps you are importing the framework in the same project so the compiler sees it twice.

Comment: Kevin, You are right. Xcode6 could have given better error info than that. It appeared that I have been trying to rename some tests and move targets around. After cleaning up all frameworks linking and binary embedding and re-adding it back the error had gone.

Comment: If you think Xcode should do a better job -> https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 6):

You many be building that that file for two app targets, one is the app itself and another a possible embedded framework. Check the file inspector on that file and the one it is being used and and then look at the imports of those files the class is being used in.

Comment: This answer guided me to my solution. I had an extension defined in my app's source code and I was trying to refer the extension code within my unit tests target. In the target membership for the extension, I selected my app target and tests target. But in the tests code, I had `@testable import AppTarget` which resulted in, as the problem says, XCode displaying my extension code twice in the autocomplete. Removing `@testable import ...` in my tests fixed the issue.

Comment: @levibostian, thank you, I had same problem and your comment helped me to understand it. But I think you should rather remove test target from target membership and keep  @ testable import ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a file that was included in multiple targets had added an `import` to one of those targets. I assume Xcode 13 did this automatically when I changed some code.

Removing the import resolved the issue.

[image]